In ruby, custom method does not work on File builtin class
I want to create a custom method on Object class and Array class.
It works perfectly with array of Integer, Strings, etc. but not for File.
Weird!
class Object
    def foo
        puts("Object#foo on #{self.inspect}")
    end
end

class Array
    def foo
        puts("Array#foo on #{self.inspect}")
        self.each do |e| 
            e.foo
        end
    end
end

Then,
a = [1,2]
a.foo

Displays:

Array#foo on [1, 2]
Object#foo on 1
Object#foo on 2

But,
b = [File.new('f1','w'),File.new('f2','w')]
b.foo

Only displays:

Array#foo on [#<File:f1>, #<File:f2>]


FYI the self. parts are superfluous. And the loop could be shortened to each(&:foo).

Extending the Ruby core classes is rarely a good idea. You risk clobbering built in methods and they do not behave like normal Ruby classes in many ways since they are [at least partially] implemented in C. Use the Delegator pattern instead to create your own class that wraps the core classes or create a module which you extend the instance with instead of messing with every object in the whole runtime.

Your issue is not Object#foo, instead it is the fact that you are assuming puts is Kernel#puts; however, in the context of File it is actually IO#puts.

puts(obj, ...) → nil
Writes the given object(s) to ios. Writes a newline after any that do not already end with a newline sequence. Returns nil.
The stream must be opened for writing. If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line. Each given object that isn’t a string or array will be converted by calling its to_s method. If called without arguments, outputs a single newline.

So instead of outputting to STDOUT as you are expecting it is writing that puts statement to the file (which is the ios in this case).
To solve this you can call Kernel#puts explicitly:
class Object
  def foo
    Kernel.puts("Object#foo on #{self.inspect}")
  end
end

Then
b = [File.new('f1','w'),File.new('f2','w')]
b.foo
# Array#foo on [#<File:f1>, #<File:f2>]
# Object#foo on #<File:f1>
# Object#foo on #<File:f2>
# => [#<File:f1>, #<File:f2>]

Pedantic implementation detail
Technically speaking Kernel#puts is $stdout.puts, which is IO#puts where $stdout is the ios but when you call puts (without a receiver) in the general context of Object (including main) it is the Kernel#puts method you are calling because of the Kernel module's  inclusion in Object.

Thank you so mutch engineersmnky. You saved my day!
